# calling menu from other activity

Tags: android

please guide me how can i call the menu on the other activity

Like here is the main activity

```
package com.droidnova.android.howto.optionmenu;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ControlMenu extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.settings:     
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowSettings.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
            break;
            case R.id.services:     Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the text!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
            case R.id.Quit: 

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {                         
                        ControlMenu.this.finish();

                        // The following makes the Android Gods frown upon me
                        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }).start();
                break;
            default:    
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

now i have make another activity in which i need to show the same menu in this

```
package com.droidnova.android.howto.optionmenu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ShowSettings extends Activity {

    Prefs myprefs = null;

    final String tag = "CH12:ShowSettings";

    AlertDialog.Builder adb;// = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        setContentView(R.layout.showsettings);

        this.myprefs = new Prefs(getApplicationContext());

        // load screen
        PopulateScreen();

        this.adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        final Button savebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settingssave);

        // create anonymous click listener to handle the "save"
        savebutton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {

                    // get the string and do something with it.

                    final EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailaddress);
                    if (email.getText().length() == 0) {

                        AlertDialog ad = ShowSettings.this.adb.create();
                        ad.setMessage("Please Enter Your Email Address");
                        ad.show();
                        return;
                    }

                    final EditText serverurl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.serverurl);
                    if (serverurl.getText().length() == 0) {
                        AlertDialog ad = ShowSettings.this.adb.create();
                        ad.setMessage("Please Enter The Server URL");
                        ad.show();
                        return;
                    }

                    // save off values
                    ShowSettings.this.myprefs.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
                    ShowSettings.this.myprefs.setServer(serverurl.getText().toString());
                    ShowSettings.this.myprefs.save();

                    // we're done!
                    finish();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i(ShowSettings.this.tag, "Failed to Save Settings [" + e.getMessage() + "]");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void PopulateScreen() {
        try {
            final EditText emailfield = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailaddress);
            final EditText serverurlfield = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.serverurl);

            emailfield.setText(this.myprefs.getEmail());
            serverurlfield.setText(this.myprefs.getServer());
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

what should i write in the above code so my menu can also appear over here .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the menu as an xml resource, then you can access it from everywhere. Check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html). If you need to pass a certain data from only one activity to the other, extending Application seems too much, given you could just pass the info as en extra in the Intent. Besides there are "dangers" in that way of doing things (because of the activity lyfecicle) so you should use SharedPreferences in that case (instead of creating an Application global variable).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share some information or data or lists (or anything really) with your app, you should look at the following link and make your app as follows:

[How to declare global variables in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables/708317#708317)